# Powershell: Remove folder that are already present in a previous folder

Tags: powershell, directory-structure

Let's say that I have a folder which contains many subfolders with mainIDs and SubIDs into those mainID folders:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\user\main folder\folder'
```

So for example

```
$IDs = 'C:\Users\user\main folder\folder\mainID'
$SubIDs = 'C:\Users\user\main folder\folder\mainID\subID'
```

What I also have is another folder which contains a previous iteration of IDs saved in another folder (called historyfolder)

```
$path2 = 'C:\Users\user\main folder\historyfolder'
```

How do I delete folders that are in the "folder" of $path AND $path2 (i.e. IDs that were previously already populated). Note that it is a tricky one, as the folders really need to be identical to be removed.
To clarify, I want mainIDs and subIDs that are unique to "folder", so not existing yet in the historyfolder. All others need to be removed

Ps. because the path is tricky (space between main folder) I used:

```
$path -replace ' ', '` '
$path2 -replace ' ', '` '
```

Anyone up for the challenge?

Example folder structure:
In'C:\Users\user\main folder\folder':

- ID 1, contains 2 sub IDs: ID A, ID B
- ID 2, contains 2 sub IDs: ID C, ID D
- ID 3, ...
- ID 4, ...

Example folder structure:
In 'C:\Users\user\main folder\historyfolder':

- ID 2, contains 2 sub IDs: ID C, ID D
- ID 44, ...
- ID 55, ...

Expected result in folder:

- ID 1, with all contents
- ID 3, with all contents
- ID 4, with all contents

Comment: Please clarify your question. Add more examples.

Comment: @AlexeyI.Kuzhel, Clarification added with examples